# Is sequential recommendation many-to-one problem or many-to-many problem?

Tags: many-to-many, recommendation-engine, many-to-one, seq2seq

When using sequential models like GRU, Attention, or transformer in recommendation area,
do we define sequential recommendation as many-to-one or many-to-many(seq2seq)?

Or does it depend on situations?

With sequential click input data, predicting another sequences seems little bit weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the majority of works are many-to-one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).